# How do I use Distribute in integral?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I use of `Distribute` for multiply a parameter in Integral.  I write the following code:

```
Distribute[
 p*Integrate[(u[0][x] + p*u[1][x] + p^2*u[2][x])/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, 
    t}]]
```

I want the following output:

```
Integrate[(p*u[0][x])/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}] + 
 Integrate[(p^2*u[1][x])/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}] + 
     Integrate[Plus[(p^3*u[2][x])/Sqrt[t - x]], {x, 0, t}]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exp = p Integrate[(u[0][x] + p u[1][x] + p^2 u[2][x]) / Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}]; 

ExpandAll[exp] /.  a_ Integrate[b_, c_] :> (Integrate[a #, c] & /@ b)
```

[image]

To have the p's outside `Integrate`s:

```
ExpandAll[exp] /.  p Integrate[b_,  c_] :>
  ((p Replace[#, Except[p^_.] :> 1, Infinity] Integrate[  # /. p -> 1, c]) & /@ b)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Is there any war for the following output: `p*Integrate[u[0][x]/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}] + p^2*Integrate[u[1][x]/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}] + p^3*Integrate[u[2][x]/Sqrt[t - x], {x, 0, t}]`

Comment: @AbdolAli, maybe `ExpandAll[exp] /. 
 p Integrate[b_, 
    c_] :> (( 
      p Replace[#, Except[p^_.] :> 1, 
        Infinity] Integrate[  # /. p -> 1, c]) & /@ b) `?